# String.Parse() To Custom Object Using Specified Format

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, string-interpolation, string.format

### EDITED TO REWORK AND (HOPEFULLY) SIMPLIFY THE QUESTION

I was working on a method for taking a `String` value and splitting it into its component parts for populating a custom structured object when a question occurred to me: Methods exist for parsing strings into "well-known" objects like `System.Net.IPAddress` or `System.DateTime` (*e.g., `DateTime.Parse()`, `DateTime.TryParse()`, or `DateTime.ParseExact()`*), but these objects use well-defined structures that don't change.

Nothing (*at least, that I've been able to find*) is available that can "quickly" parse a string into a custom-defined object/structure. Is there a way to achieve the same result by basically "*reversing*" the functionality of either the base `String.Format()` method or string interpolation to extract a target object's property/field values from a given string?

***For the purposes of this question and my examples, I'll refer to this hypothetical method as `String.Parse()`***

For example, given an object with the following definition:

```vb
Public Class LastModified
    Public Property User As String = Nothing
    Public Property FromIP As String = Nothing
    Public Property InterfaceName As String = Nothing
    Public Property Method As String = Nothing
    Public Property ModifiedDate As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
End Class
```

I was thinking of something like one of the following pseudocode alternatives:

```vb
' PSEUDOCODE - NOT OPERATIONAL - DO NOT USE
Dim LMBString As String = "admin 192.168.168.168:X0 UI 03/26/2022 15:43:38"
Dim LMB As New LastModified

' USING "BASIC" String.Format() SYNTAX
LMBString.Parse("{0} {1}:{2} {3} {4}", 
                LMB.User,
                LMB.FromIP,
                LMB.InterfaceName,
                LMB.Method,
                LMB.ModifiedDate)

' USING STRING INTERPOLATION SYNTAX
LMBString.Parse($"{LMB.User} {LMB.FromIP}:{LMB.InterfaceName} {LMB.Method} {LMB.ModifiedDate}")
```

Perhaps this functionality is available through a 3rd-party library, and I suppose I could probably build a `.Parse()` extension method that could achieve this goal *relatively* easily, but I wanted to go ahead and see if someone else had already invented that particular wheel, and my *Google-fu* may simply be too weak. As stated above, I've not been able to find implementations of either of these pseudocode operations currently available natively in .NET (*I'm using Framework 4.7 for my current project*), but I don't mind looking stupid to ask a question that might have a simple solution - especially if it helps someone else who faces the same issues.

---

Just for reference purposes, in my current implementation, I'm using the following (simplified) code, which is *totally functional* and provides the results I'm looking for. I'm satisfied to keep using this "as-is", but I couldn't help wondering if there might be a way to achieve the same goal with fewer lines of code.

```vb
Public Function ParseStringToLastModifiedObject As LastModified
    Dim LMBString As String = "admin 192.168.168.168:X0 UI 03/26/2022 15:43:38"
    Dim LMBBuffer As String() = LMBString.Split(" "c)
    Dim LMBReturn As New LastModified

    With LMBReturn
        Dim IPBuffer As String() = LMBBuffer(1).Split(":"c)

        .User = LMBBuffer(0) '-> "admin"
        .Method = LMBBuffer(2) '-> "UI"
        .ModifiedDate = CDate(LMBBuffer(3) & " " & LMBBuffer(4)) '-> #3/26/2022 15:43:38#
        .FromIP = IPBuffer(0) '-> "192.168.168.168"
        .InterfaceName = IPBuffer(1) '-> "X0"
    End With

    Return LMBReturn
End Function
```

Comment: These methods do the *opposite* of parsing. They don't extract tokens from a larger string, they generate a larger string using a template and values

Comment: In any case, the string you posted isn't  JSON. You can't have multiple roots in a JSON string. You can't use a JSON object as an attribute name. Whatever `{LMB.User} {LMB.FromIP}:{LMB.InterfaceName}` is, it's not JSON

Comment: Finally, .NET *does* have a built-in JSON parser, [System.Text.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json). In .NET Core, it's part of the SDK. In .NET Old, you have to add the NuGet package explicitly. Web API and Razor Pages projects use JSON.NET, which means a built-in JSON parser is available there as well. In other applications you can add the package

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thank you for the feedback. To address each of your points: **1)** I'm aware of the actual functionality of `String.Format` and string interpolation, which is why I specifically called it `.Parse()` in my pseudocode examples. **2)** The string that I'm parsing (*as listed in my functional `Get()` method for my `Property`*) is simply one of the property values from my parsed JSON object. I'm sorry if I introduced confusion by referring to JSON. **3)** I'm aware of the "built-in" namespace for parsing JSON. I just happen to be using Newtonsoft's library b/c I'm used to it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I've updated my question to hopefully clarify what I'm working with, as well as what I'm specifically trying to accomplish. Please let me know if it's still unclear in any way. This question is not about JSON or deserialization. It is simply about finding a "better" way to parse a single string value. I mention JSON only because that's where the `String` comes from and the (working) code is specifically taken from a deserialized JSON object.

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat You would need to write the code to parse the required parse before being able to parse the input. If the example was the *minimum* required to demonstrate the problem then it might be easier to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Thank you, and I apologize for apparently being unclear. I thought that my pseudocode examples would demonstrate explicitly what I was asking for. Perhaps I should strip out all of my "explanation" and the working code samples I provided and just leave the pseudocode examples.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Thank you again. I've completely reworked the question (and edited the title) to try to "boil it down" to the essence of what I'm trying to ask. I've removed any references to unrelated topics (JSON) and included a bit more clarification for my own thought process, but the question and context are exactly the same as what I originally intended. Please let me know if there is still any ambiguity or confusion.

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat I reckon that information is lost in the process of going from separate variables into one string, so more work (programming) is needed to get the information back than to lose the information (String.Format).

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I totally get that. For example, a "format string" that looks like `"Name: {0} -Age: {1}"` would drop the "extra" information around the placeholders in such a method (*which is exactly what I would expect/want to happen*). That's one of the reasons, in the absence of a "built-in" method, I explicitly mentioned the possibility of building an extension method or use of a 3rd-party library to achieve the stated goals.

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat In the example in the question, you'd add a constructor to the LastModified class that takes the string as a parameter, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243529/discussion-between-g-hosa-phat-and-andrew-morton).